# ggRadar with interactive=TRUE cannot change color

Tags: r, colors, interactive, ggiraphextra

I want to make an **interactive** graph on R with the **ggRadar** function in `ggiraphExtra`. I want to define different colors for each group.

However, as soon as I use the option `Interactive=true` I can't change the colors :(

Can anyone help me?

```
mycolors <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(3,  "Paired"))(3)

mycolors
> "#A6CEE3" "#1F78B4" "#B2DF8A"


p_static=ggRadar(mtcars, aes(colour = cyl, fill=cyl), rescale = TRUE, legend.position = "left",  interactive = FALSE, use.label = TRUE)

p_static+scale_color_manual(values = mycolors) +scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors)
```

works, but now with `interactive=TRUE`:

```
p_interactive=ggRadar(mtcars, aes(colour = cyl, fill=cyl), rescale = TRUE, legend.position = "left",  interactive = TRUE, use.label = TRUE)

p_interactive+scale_color_manual(values = mycolors) +scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors)
```

doesn't work...

[image: radar plot]